# C++: const pointers when using Visual Studio compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constants

I have a strange situation with the C++ compiler of Visual Studio 2012.

This is merely a test code, which should fail:

```
char s1[5] = "new";
char s2[5] = "old";
char const* p = s1;   
p++;                  // should fail
p = s2;               // this line should also fail;
```

Can someone tell me, why it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reasons those lines should fail. Perhaps you are confusing `char const*` with `char * const`. In the first case, the `char`s are `const`. In the second, the pointer is `const`. In your code, since the pointer is not `const`, it's fine to do both `p++` and `p = s2;`.

Remember the rule: “`const` applies to its left, unless there is nothing, in which case it applies to its right.”

Comment: Are "char const* p = s1"  and  "const char* p = s1" identical ?

Comment: "char const x = 5" and "const char x = 5" too ?

Comment: @moller1111 Yes. Here you can read more about it. A bit too detailed but worth it. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking that the incrementation should not work because it is `const char*`. However the `const` here specifies that **what is pointed to can not be modified**. Not that the pointer can be modified.

However this is illegal.

```
char s1[5] = "new";
char s2[5] = "old";
char const* const p = s1;
            ^^^^   
p++;                  // should not compile
p = s2;
```

**C++ `const` qualifier applies to what is on left of it, if there is something on the left. otherwise it applies to what is on the right.**

Read [**Here**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html) for more info about `const` correctness.

Answer (score 2):

```
const int x;      // constant int
x = 2;            // illegal - can't modify x

const int* pX;    // changeable pointer to constant int
*pX = 3;          // illegal -  can't use pX to modify an int
pX = &someOtherIntVar;      // legal - pX can point somewhere else

int* const pY;              // constant pointer to changeable int
*pY = 4;                    // legal - can use pY to modify an int
pY = &someOtherIntVar;      // illegal - can't make pY point anywhere else

const int* const pZ;        // const pointer to const int
*pZ = 5;                    // illegal - can't use pZ to modify an int
pZ = &someOtherIntVar;      // illegal - can't make pZ point anywhere else
```

PS: I blatantly copied this [from here](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html) , I think having it here as well will be useful somewhere in the future.